# VLC will not launch 15.10

Tags: vlc, segmentation-fault

As a relative noob to linux,I will need some detailed help on how to fix this issue.

When I try to launch VLC in Terminal, it shows :

```
yohji@htpc:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[0000000000ff5148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

A first thing to try is to reset the vlc configuration files to their defaults by running the following from a Terminal window:

```
vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

This might be enough to get vlc running again...

Comment: Unfortunately it still Segmentation faults.
It hasn't run at all on this 15.10 fresh install?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/qt5-default/5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9

After some further research my system is only accessible via ssh, so I was informed to install the above.

Comment: no success still. same segmentation fault every time i try to launch.

Comment: fixed for me...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's causing this, but to work around it at the moment you can do this:

```
vlc -I skins2
```

(HT: [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863961/vlc-crashes-in-kubuntu-16-10))

This works for me on Kubuntu 16.10 running vlc 2.2.4.