# VLC crashes in kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, vlc, qt

I have upgraded to kubuntu 16.10 from 16.04 recently, and along with it came a new version of vlc 2.2.4.

But whenever i open vlc it gave me a generic segfault:

```
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
[00005603dd50c038] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[1]    13268 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vlc
```

But it works fine when i do

```
vlc -I skins
```

So i guess the problem is most likely with my qt installation.
I have both qt4 and qt5 libraries installed in my system. vlc has a libqt4_plugin.so i think it is using qt4.

How do i resolve this issue i have tried purging all my vlc config files and also doing:

```
/usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f usr/lib/vlc/plugins
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you recently have updated to Ubuntu 16.10
For me it worked when I reenabled the sources in the update manager.
You find these files in /etc/apt/sources.d
Then I updateded and upgraded my packages. With the new versions installed vlc started to work again.